# Is it possible to reject sharing of a document in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

In real world scenarios, people can offer each other something. But the other party can reject it, either formally and politely or in any other way.

What matters is that sharing process is a two-sided process. But in Google Drive, I have no control upon what others offer me.

My friends are sharing more and more items with me, which makes searching through documents more and more difficult. Is there anyway to reject something that has been shared with you on Google Drive?

Comment: So you basically want to hide documents that you don't own? If you select _Owned by me_ from the search box dropdown, you won't see documents that are shared with you.

Answer (score 1):

On the "Shared with me", you see list of all the documents, which have been shared with you.

You can select each or group of documents and click "Remove". Then you won't see it anymore.